# how to uniqely identify the observations in the group of variables?

Tags: r, grouping

I have a sample dataframe "`z`" as follows:

```
deaths  sex race    smokes  pyears
10  Female  White   0   1410
14  Male    White   1   1974
14  Female  Black   0   1974
16  Male    Black   1   2256
17  Male    Black   0   2397
18  Female  NA  1   2538
19  NA  Black   0   2679
20  Female  White   1   2820
20  Female  Black   0   2820
21  Male    Black   1   2961
```

I like to create the new variables "`group`" that combine the variables race and sex. This new variable uniquely identifies groups of observations in a daaframe "z". The expected output is

```
 group
    1
    2
    3
    4
    4
    6
    5
    1
    3
    4
```

I am wondering how do we code this in R?

Comment: You're probably looking for `interaction()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing I was thinking:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "deaths  sex race    smokes  pyears
10  Female  White   0   1410
14  Male    White   1   1974
14  Female  Black   0   1974
16  Male    Black   1   2256
17  Male    Black   0   2397
18  Female  NA  1   2538
19  NA  Black   0   2679
20  Female  White   1   2820
20  Female  Black   0   2820
21  Male    Black   1   2961",header = TRUE,sep = "")

dat$sex <- factor(dat$sex,exclude = NULL)
dat$race <- factor(dat$race,exclude = NULL)

with(dat,interaction(sex,race))

 [1] Female.White Male.White   Female.Black Male.Black   Male.Black   Female.NA    NA.Black     Female.White Female.Black
[10] Male.Black  
Levels: Female.Black Male.Black NA.Black Female.White Male.White NA.White Female.NA Male.NA NA.NA
```

It looks like you wanted to include the NAs, rather than drop them, hence the explicit `factor` calls. Obviously, the resulting factor can be converted to integers using `as.integer`, although the actual numbers won't likely be in the order you specified, since R will order things alphabetically, rather than how they appear in your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
dat <- read.table(text="deaths  sex race    smokes  pyears
10  Female  White   0   1410
14  Male    White   1   1974
14  Female  Black   0   1974
16  Male    Black   1   2256
17  Male    Black   0   2397
18  Female  NA  1   2538
19  NA  Black   0   2679
20  Female  White   1   2820
20  Female  Black   0   2820
21  Male    Black   1   2961", header=TRUE)

library(qdap)
factor(paste2(dat[, 2:3], ,FALSE))

#for numeric:
as.numeric(factor(paste2(dat[, 2:3], ,FALSE)))
```

But as Joran pointed out your numeric expectations aren't the same as how R will make them.  You'd have to use `levels` inside `factor` to order the levels as you desire.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for the alternative solution!